# Why can rails not find a route created by a helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I created a [member route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-member-routes) in rails 4:

```
resources :line_items do
    post 'decrement', on: :member
end
```

and gave it a matching method in the line_items controller:

```
def decrement
    @cart = current_cart

    @line_item = @cart.line_items.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @line_item.decrement_quantity

    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to shop_path, notice: 'Line item was successfully updated.' }
        format.js {@current_item = @line_item}
        format.json { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.js {@current_item = @line_item}
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

But when I try to make a button:

```
<%= button_to 'X', decrement_line_item_path(item)  %>
```

I get this error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/carts/25"
```

**What gives?**

Comment: can you paste the output of `rake routes` for this controller?

Answer (score 3):

Your error message is:

```
No route matches [POST] "/carts/25"
```

But I was expecting the route to be: `/line_items/25/decrement`, not `/carts/25`

Are your `line_items` routes already nested under `carts`?  If so, you could unnest the decrement action like so:

```
# in config/routes.rb
resources :carts do
  resources :line_items
end

resources :line_items, only: [] do
  post 'decrement', on: :member
end
```

Comment: Excellent, I'll give this a shot later today. That button was dropped into the `:show` view of the `Cart` controller (I probably should have mentioned that in my question). Does that tell you anything else or should your answer still work?

Comment: If the solution doesn't work, then if you post the output of running: `rake routes | grep decrement` then we'll take another look at it (that is to say post the output of rake routes filtered to only include lines with the word decrement in it.)

Answer (score 0):

```
resources :line_items do
    post 'decrement', on: :member
end
```

Upon `CONTROLLER='line_items' rake routes`, here is the following output

```
decrement_line_item POST   /line_items/:id/decrement(.:format) line_items#decrement
         line_items GET    /line_items(.:format)               line_items#index
                    POST   /line_items(.:format)               line_items#create
      new_line_item GET    /line_items/new(.:format)           line_items#new
     edit_line_item GET    /line_items/:id/edit(.:format)      line_items#edit
          line_item GET    /line_items/:id(.:format)           line_items#show
                    PUT    /line_items/:id(.:format)           line_items#update
                    DELETE /line_items/:id(.:format)           line_items#destroy
```

So in your html button part, you need add the `POST` method.

```
<%= button_to 'X', decrement_line_item_path(item), method: :post  %>
```

Comment: But as far as I know `button_to` takes `post` method by default!

Comment: Ahh... yes. that was out of my mind. must be something in routes then.